# SQL multiple column unique

Tags: sql, sql-server, unique

I have a table with the following columns: `ID`, `text1`, `text2`.

What to do in order to make `(text1,text2)` unique, for example: values `(1,a,b)`, `(2,b,b)`, `(3,a,a)` are allowed, but `(4,a,b)` will not be inserted because `(a,b)` is repeating?

Comment: Which Database? Create unique index on these three columns.

Comment: @user3162968 What are you using MySql or SQL server. You can create a composite key on the two column

Comment: SQL server. Dhruvjoshi, I would give +2 instead of +1 iff I could, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a unique composite key:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
ADD CONSTRAINT uc_my_table UNIQUE (id, text1, text2)
```